# Outline one indent back

Tags: spacing, formatting

Hi i want to do something like this.

```
1) Level 1
    1.a)  Level 2
        1.a.i)  Level 3.
        1.a.ii)  Level 3.
        text at same identation that Level 2
```

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{outlines}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{outline}[enumerate]
   \1 Level 1 
      \2 Level 2
         \3 Level 3
         \3 Level 4
      \2 text at same indentation that Level 2
\end{outline}
\end{document}
```

but this code makes another bullet and i only want to write something at the same identation that level 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give the second `\2` an empty custom style: `\2[]`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{outlines}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{outline}[enumerate]
   \1 Level 1 
      \2 Level 2
         \3 Level 3
         \3 Level 4
      \2[] text at same indentation that Level 2
\end{outline}
\end{document}
```

[image]